# Multi file_get_contents with different results

Tags: php

Id like to add 3-4 file_get_contents and to show different results. This is what am using now:

```
<?php
$listOfIPS = explode("\n", file_get_contents('https://domain1.com/ips.txt'));

if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $listOfIPS)) {
    echo '{"type":"Valid"}';
}
else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

Now I want to search for IP's in 3 .txt files at once.

```
If ip found on file1.txt should show content {"type":"Valid"}
If ip found on file2.txt should show content {"type":"invalid"}
If ip found on file3.txt should show content {"type":"fix"}
```

I have tried like this:

```
<?php
$listOfIPS = explode("\n", file_get_contents('https://domain1.com/ips.txt'));
$listOfIPS2 = explode("\n", file_get_contents('https://domain1.com/ips2.txt'));
$listOfIPS3 = explode("\n", file_get_contents('https://domain1.com/ips3.txt'));

if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $listOfIPS)) {
    echo '{"type":"Valid"}';
}
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $listOfIPS2)) {
    echo '{"type":"invalid"}';
}
if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $listOfIPS3)) {
    echo '{"type":"fix"}';
}

else {
    echo '';
}
?>
```

Without success :)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What error do u exactly get on executing the second script ?

Comment: Can you provide several strings of each operated file?

Comment: What OS are you operating on? Try using the `PHP_EOL` (EOL = End Of Line) constant for the exploding for compatibility on systems that use other line ends than `\n`

Comment: @Aamir the script shows the result else {
echo '';
}

Comment: guys am not familiar with php using other strings etc. If someone can post me the php code I should replace will be great!

Comment: It would be helpful if u can post the content of the file of ips, ips1..

Comment: in the ip.txt should listed ip only. One ip in row.

Comment: You should use `elseif` for the 2nd and 3rd occurrence of your `if` because you want exactly one echo to be executed. Now you are checking condition 1, 2 and 3 separately and your `else` is always executed, when condition 3 is false, regardless of condition 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your code to:

```
$listOfIPS = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('https://domain1.com/ips.txt'));
$listOfIPS2 = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('https://domain1.com/ips2.txt'));
$listOfIPS3 = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('https://domain1.com/ips3.txt'));

if (!empty($listOfIPS) && in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $listOfIPS)) {
    echo '{"type":"Valid"}';
}
if (!empty($listOfIPS2) && in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $listOfIPS2)) {
    echo '{"type":"invalid"}';
}
if (!empty($listOfIPS3) && in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $listOfIPS3)) {
    echo '{"type":"fix"}';
}
else {
    echo '';
}
```